# Overriding the same function twice

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

In order to ask for permissions during runtime I use the `RequestPermissions` function.

I use the `RequestPermissions` function twice. Once in a fragment (`void Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment.RequestPermissions`) and once in the main activity (`void Activity.RequestPermissions`).

In order to do that, I override the `OnRequestPermissionsResult` function twice- it seems like that `void Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment.RequestPermissions` actually turns to `void MainActivity.OnRequestPermissionsResult` when it ends. How could I use the other `OnRequestPermissionsResult`?

The main thing is, what happens when overriding the same function twice? Which version will apply? The `OnRequestPermissionsResult` is my problem and brought here as an example, but I guess that it belongs to a bigger thing.

Another way to ask is how can I determine which function `RequestPermissions` will call when done?

Comment: C# or Java? I assume you're not using both at the same time for this one problem..

Comment: C# @BrootsWaymb

Comment: in your fragment,how do you request for permission?`ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions()` or `RequestPermissions()` directly ？

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT As mentioned, `Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment.RequestPermissions`

Comment: could you show your `RequestPermissions` and `OnRequestPermissionsResult` code？i test,i could get the callback both in the Activity's `OnRequestPermissionsResult` and Fragment's `OnRequestPermissionsResult`

Comment: What do you mean? I didn't code it, it's a built in function..

Comment: i will show an example below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the parent activity,i have an `OnRequestPermissionsResult` method,

```
 public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, "Activity", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
```

then in fragment,i use a button to click and call to request permission:

```
button.Click += delegate
   {
     RequestPermissions(new string[] { Manifest.Permission.Camera }, 0);
   };
```

and also have an `OnRequestPermissionsResult` method in fragment:

```
 public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(Activity, "Fragment", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
```

finaly the callback will enter activity's `OnRequestPermissionsResult`,then enter fragment's `OnRequestPermissionsResult`,so you could custom `requestCode` to distinguish which side of the request.

Comment: But the question is, which code will be executed first? And what is the purpose of `base.OnRequestPermissionsResult`?

Comment: it is the same ！

Comment: it call parent activity's `OnRequestPermissionsResult` first,then call fragment's and base.OnRequestPermissionsResult is default

Comment: Solved my problem, thanks a lot. I still don't understand why would `base.OnRequestPermissionsResult` in the implementation of the `Activity` will lead to the implementation of the `Fragment`. I thought that `base` calls the parent class and not the derived one..

Comment: you only add  base.OnRequestPermissionsResult in activity,it will continue to call the fragment's  OnRequestPermissionsResult .if it's helpful for you ,could you mark it and vote up,thank you

Comment: I still don't understand why the Activity's one is called first, and why the Fragment's comes later.. How base connects between the two? Could you explain the process?